# Auto-refresh React props from Redux store on `new Date()` day change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native app which shows a new quote from an array each day. The idea being that you open the app and it will show you today's quote. Open it up tomorrow and it'll show you tomorrow's new quote.

Now, I grab the current quote from the Redux store in the `mapStateToProps` method in one of my top-level Components, like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const currentQuote = getCurrentQuote(
    state
  );
  return {
    quote: currentQuote
  };
};
```

And `getCurrentQuote`:

```
const getCurrentQuote = (state, day) => {
  const index = getDayOfYear(!day ? new Date() : new Date(day));
  return state.quotes[index];
};
```

My exact question is, if someone opens the app, and the date has changed (ie. a new day), nothing changes. No new quote.

Obviously I could have the user refresh the app manually and update the quote, but I'd rather have it auto-update.

Beyond having a constantly running `setInterval` running, is there a better way for the Component to respond to `new Date` changes (ie. new day).

Potentially `AppState` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html

Comment: Try passing **new Date()** as the second parameter while calling your getCurrentQuote function in your mapStateToProp.

Comment: What are you concern with using a `setInterval`? I don't believe there is an issue with your usage of it

Comment: @ryan-c I honestly don’t know, it just doesn’t feel right to have one running indefinitely. Concerns over memory etc

Comment: I suggest you use any react-native or node cron library instead. Couldn't post answer because I had few information and how it's going to apply on your code.